# Vagrant + Virtualbox on Debian Bullseye

Tags: virtualbox, debian, vagrant

I've got Debian Bullseye installed on my computer and I want to play a bit
with Vagrant. Unfortunately, I stumbled upon two problems that at first sight
are not related, however in order to give full overview I list them both:

1. While installing `vagrant` package from repos, Debian automatically removes `virtualbox` and `virtualbox-qt` packages, and vice versa!
   When I try to reinstall `virtualbox` Debian informs me that during the installation `vagrant` and `vagrant-libvirt` will be removed. Why? Are there any obstacles
   that those packages cannot work together on Debian?
   On [bullseye's webpage about vagrant package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/vagrant) you can only find that:
   ''Vagrant upstream uses Oracle’s VirtualBox by default to create its virtual machines. On Debian, Vagrant will use libvirt/KVM by default as VirtualBox is not part of Debian main, but will use VirtualBox if it's installed.''

Anyway, I circumvented this issue by installing `virtualbox` from official
Debian's repos, and downloading
standalone, appImaged `vagrant` binary from [vagrant's official page](https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant), and
copying it into some system path directory. Now both of them are working...

2. The second problem is that even for simple `Vagrantfile` like:

```
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
    
      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
      vb.gui = true
    
      vb.cpus = 2
      vb.memory = 1024
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "128"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--clipboard", "bidirectional"]  
      end
    
      config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
         apt-get update
         apt-get install -y emacs
      SHELL
    
    end
```

the commands from `config.vm.provision "shell", inline`
block are not executed! What is more I cannot `vagrant ssh` into
vm. I keep obtaining:

```
VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`
to start the virtual machine.
```

Details: After `vagrant up` the vagrant box is created (I can see it in virtualbox),
virtualbox is being launched
and I got the virtual machine login screen. I can login and everything is ok (in virtualbox window).

However the last messages from command line say that:

```
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
```

The full output from the command line is here:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/ubuntu-18.04
==> default: Adding box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' (v202212.11.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-18.04/versions/202212.11.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Successfully added box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' (v202212.11.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'bento/ubuntu-18.04' version '202212.11.0' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: debian-vagrant_default_1676627515085_33587
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

I found somewhere that disabled VT features in BIOS might cause this kind of
problems. I checked this and I had them enabled in my BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant is not compatible with the latest version of virtualbox (7.x).
You have the compatible versions here https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/providers/virtualbox

Comment: Thanks for the link. Nevertheless, the clue, you provided, does not explain the fact that Vagrant 2.3.4 and VirtualBox 7.0 work as expected when I install them on Windows. I tried with VirtualBox 6.1 installed from Oracle's site, however this in a turn gave rise to problems with dkms and after playing a bit with this I gave up for a while. So I'd rather blame Debian for the problems.

Comment: I'm fighting with this now too. That [vagrant link](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/providers/virtualbox) links to the VirtualBox downloads page, but what is provided is a debian package, and to actually install it you also have to install all of its dependencies, and their dependencies, of which there are many. So while it's possible, there is definitely no one-liner command that will do it for you... I wonder if there is a tool that can help me generate an `apt install` command for all the dependencies of a debian package, assuming debian provides them all...

Comment: Aha, `apt -f install` will do just that!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/40050/207584

Comment: Not very related to this question but maybe useful to someone: If you, like me, are trying to run this on an AWS EC2 instance, you may soon discover that most EC2 instance types don't support virtual machines, and the ones that do are expensive. I hear that maybe you can make VirtualBox run your guest OS in an emulated mode, but then maybe performance is terrible. So maybe don't try to run a guest OS on EC2. Just launch another EC2 instance running the OS you want.